# Standard order for drawing a prism?

Tags: opengl, drawing, rendering, standards, immediate-mode

Is there a standard order for drawing faces on a rectangular prism with OpenGL? If I were to write a "prism" function, would I want to write it to render in a specific order? Are there any technical reasons for drawing, say, the back face before the front face?

Comment: Front-to-back painting allows ["early z kill"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15673187/622391), where obscured elements won't need to be painted at all

Comment: Unless you have transparency, in which case you want back-to-front.

Answer (score 1):

The are two possibilities how to interpret/answer your question.

**The interpretation that the z-buffer is disabled**

If this is the case then all primitives you draw will be drawn in that order.
So you need to write it in that specific order.

**The interpretation that the z-buffer is enabled**

If this is the case, it doesn't care in what order you send the polygons to the graphicscard.
There is no standard order